# Is $C$ projective as $C[x]$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I'm asking myself if $C = C[X]/(x)$ is a projective/flat $C[X]$ module. I found on the internet that this isn't the case, but on the other hand we have $ C[X] = C \oplus xC[X]$, so $C$ is a direct summon of a free $C[X]$ module. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: That’s a direct sum of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces, but not  of $\mathbb C[X]$-modules.

Comment: Why? Both are $C[x]$ modules right? So I can take the direct sum, and this does not depend on the mother ring?

Comment: A projective module is a sub-module of a free module, hence has no torsion. But your module is annihilated by $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb C[x]$ does not have direct summands as a $\mathbb C[x]$ module. There are simply no nonzero submodules intersecting to $\{0\}$.

The illusion I think you are under is that that the constant term $\lambda$ in the polynomials can be exchanged for the coset $\lambda +(x)$, which of course it cannot. In $\mathbb C[x]$, $1\cdot x$ is nonzero, whereas considered as the module $\mathbb C[x]/(x)$ multiplying anything nonzero by $x$ results in the zero coset.  They just aren't isomorphic.

---

> But How could I proof now in general, that this isn't a projective Moudle

I think you mean $\mathbb C[x]/(x)$(?)  If it were projective the exact sequence $0\to (x)\to \mathbb C[x]\to \mathbb C[x]/(x)\to 0$ would split, so that $(x)$ is a summand of $\mathbb C[x]$. It isn't, for the reason mentioned above.

Comment: Is it analogly true than that for a non trivial Ideal $I$ the $R$-Module $R/I$ is not projective? (if $R$ is a domain)

Comment: I mean the following, if it would be projective than $ 0\to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$ would split i.e $R/I$ would be a direct summand of $R$, but as $R$ is a domain it is torsion free (as $R$-Module) and $R/I$ isn't, so it cant be a direct summand.

Comment: You can say that for $I$ a nontrivial ideal of $R$, the module $R/I$ is projective iff $I$ is a summand of $R$. In particular, if $R$ has only trivial idempotents (as is the case for a domain), no such $I$ can be a summand.

Comment: why exactly is the idempotent condition enough for $I$ not beeing a direct summand of $R$ ?

Comment: @user1072285 In a ring with identity, a right submodule (resp. left submodule) is a summand iff it is $eR$ (resp $Re$) for some idempotent element $e$.  In general a submodule $N$ of $M$ is a summand of $M$ iff there is an idempotent $e$ of $End(M_R)$ such that $e(M)=N$.

Answer (score 3):

The claim that $C[X]\cong C[x]/(x)\oplus xC[x]$ as $C[x]$-modules is false. I imagine you’re thinking the isomorphism would look like
\begin{align*}
\phi:\,&C[x]/(x)\oplus xC[x]\to C[x] \\
&(c,xd)\mapsto c+xd.
\end{align*}
But the issue is that this isn’t an isomorphism of $C[x]$-modules. In particular, consider multiplication by $x$: we get $\phi(x(1,0))=x\phi(1,0) = x(1) = x$, if this is to be a $C[x]$-module homomorphism. But in the direct sum, $x(1,0) = (x,0) = (0,0)$ since $x=0$ in $C[x]/(x)$, and $\phi(0,0) = 0$. So this map doesn’t give an isomorphism of $C[x]$-modules.

Writing $C=C[x]/(x)$ obscures the fact that as a $C[x]$-module, multiplication by $x$ takes everything to $0$.

Comment: ahh I understand, thank you. But How could I proof now in general, that this isn't a projective Moudle (i.e there is no other decomposition of a free $C[x]$ module?

Comment: By $C$, do you mean the complex numbers? If so, then a rather convoluted argument is that $C[x]$ is a PID, and $C[x]/(x)$ is not torsion-free as a $C[x]$-module (as we saw, multiplication by $x$ acts as multiplication by $0$). Thus $C[x]/(x)$ is not flat (over a PID, flat is equivalent to torsion-free), and since projective modules are flat, this means it isn’t projective. But I am absolutely sure there is a better argument than this, perhaps using classification of f.g. modules over a PID or using the fact that submodules of $C[x]$ are precisely the ideals of $C[x]$ as a ring…

Comment: Oh, here is the argument: we need to find two submodules/ideals of $C[x]$ that intersect trivially (and add to give all of $C[x]$). But no two nonzero ideals of $C[x]$ can possibly intersect trivially, since we can always just multiply a nonzero element in one by a nonzero element in the other to get a nonzero element in their intersection.